# pass cart items through controller to another jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, dispatcher

I am trying to implement very basic shopping cart. I am struggling to **pass items** from **page1.jsp** to **page2.jsp** through spring mvc **controller**. In the GET method of the said contrller, I have these items, but these are not showing on page2.jsp. Flow looks like this

page1.jsp (checkout) **-->** controller (values available here in GET method) **-->** pag2.jsp (empty )

Here is the controller.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("cart")
public class CheckoutController 
{
    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView ShowCheckoutMenu(@ModelAttribute("cart") ArrayList<Menu> mycart, Model model)                                   
    {
       // cart items available here. im adding them to the view
        return new ModelAndView("checkout_menu", "cart", mycart);
    }
}
```

Now here is the page2.jsp

```
        <form:form modelAttribute="cart">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10%">Name</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Price Rs.</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>    

            <c:set var="total_cost" value="0" scope="page" />
            <c:forEach items="${cart}" var="cart_item">
                <tr>
                    <c:choose> 
                      <c:when test="${fn:length(cart) gt 0}">
                        <td style="width:10%">${cart_item.getMenuName()}</td>
                        <td style="width:10%">${cart_item.getMenuPrice()}</td>
                        <c:set var="total_cost" value="${total_cost + cart_item.getMenuPrice()}" scope="page"/>
                      </c:when>
                      <c:otherwise>
                        <b><i>EMPTY LIST</i></b>
                      </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>                    
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:10%">Total Cost:</td>
                <td style="width:10%"><c:out value="${total_cost}" /></td>
            </tr>                
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Now when page2.jsp is shown, it shows me EMPTY LIST, while as I said earlier, items were there in the controller and I attach them with the view. WHAT IS WRONG HERE ??? THANKS FOR INPUT.

Comment: Try accessing the values using the attribute name rather than the getter methods. For example : I mean to say try cart_item.menuName instead of cart_item.getMenuName().

Comment: And also you should iterate on mycart rather than cart.Please check that as well.When you say  ModelAndView("checkout_menu", "cart", mycart); the first parameter is the view name, the second is the model name and the third is the model object. So i guess you should be using the model object to iterate